# Not receiving posts from Facebook realtime API subscriptions with Rails and Koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-opengraph, koala, real-time-updates

Hope you can help, I'm kind of at my wit's end here....I'm working on a Rails App and running Koala to connect with the Facebook Graph API.  I want to maintain an up-to-date list of a user's friends who are using my app so I have been trying to implement the Realtime Updates functionality of the Koala gem.  My app is deployed on Heroku and I'm running Resque with Redis-to-Go to manage calls from Facebook... unfortunately, I don't seem to be receiving any even though my test pings to the Facebook server are all returning true.  Here's the code I'm working with:

```
Realtime Controller:

 class RealtimeController < ApplicationController
 skip_before_filter :logged_in_check

  layout nil
  VERIFY_TOKEN = "purple-rain"

   def create
    Friendship.real_time_update!(params)
    render :text => 'success'
  end

  def index
    Rails.logger.info("RealTimeController verification")
    render :text=>Koala::Facebook::RealtimeUpdates.meet_challenge(params, VERIFY_TOKEN)
  end

end




Friendship Controller:

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :friend_id, :user_id

   belongs_to :users, :foreign_key => "user_id"
   belongs_to :friends_ids, :class_name => "users", :foreign_key => "friend_id"

 def self.get_friends(user)
    @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(user.oauth_token)
    @friends =  @facebook.get_connection(user.fbid, "friends")

    @friends.each do |friend|

      if @friend = User.find_by_fbid(friend["id"])

         friendship = Friendship.find_or_create_by_user_id_and_friend_id!(user.id,         
                      @friend.id)

       end
    end
  end

  def self.real_time_update!(payload)
    RealtimeUpdate.new(payload).enqueue_updates!
  end

     class RealtimeUpdate < Struct.new(:payload)


    def enqueue_updates!
      remove_duplicate_ids.each do |entry|
        if (user = User.find_by_uid(entry['uid']).try(:user))
          Resque.enqueue(Resque::Job::UpdateFacebookFriends, user.id, 
                         :since=>entry['time'])
        end
      end
    end

    protected

    def remove_duplicate_ids
      payload['entry'].each_with_object({}) do |entry, hash|
        hash[entry['uid']] ||= [] << entry
      end.values.collect { |update_payloads| update_payloads.min { |entry1, entry2|     
      entry1['time']<=>entry2['time'] } }
    end


  end

end
```

Resque Job

```
 class Resque::Job::UpdateFacebookFriends

  @queue        = "facebook_friends"

   def self.perform(uid, opts={})
    ::Timeout.timeout(1800) do
      Friendship.get_friends!(User.find_by_fbid(uid))
    end
  end

end
```

Happy to provide any other info I can!!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: has my answer been heplful?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have specified `read_friendlists` permission in the rails configuration:

```
provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], :scope => 'read_friendlists, friends_location'
```

And please use function `get_connections`:

```
@facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new user.oauth_token
@friends = @facebook.get_connection user.fbid, :friends
```